# Excel VBA. How to tell macro to key in 1 to 10 down a column amd repeat until the end?

Tags: vba, excel

Currently trying to create a macro that fills in number 1 to 10 down a column and repeats until the end of my For statement. This is what I have in mind:

[image]

With a click of a button the number will start at row 3 and count to 10. Once done it will repeat until it reaches the end. I previously done a variant this program which creates repeats of 1 for 10 rows, repeat 2 for the next 10 rows and so on like so:

```
Sub fill()

Dim ID
ID = 1
For c = 1 To 34        
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c + 2, 1) = ID
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c + 3, 1) = ID
    c = c + 1
    If (c Mod 10) = 0 Then
        ID = ID + 1
    End If

Next c

End Sub
```

If I want to convert it to counting 1-10 and then repeat, what needs to be changed. I would like to reuse this code with some modifications to the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a lazy way to do this.

```
Sub Macro1(offsetIn As Integer, colIn As Integer)

offset = offsetIn - 1
Column = colIn

For c = 1 To 34

  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c + offset, colIn) = c Mod 10

  If (c Mod 10 = 0) Then
     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c + offset, colIn) = 10
  End If

Next c

End Sub
```

As for getting this macro to trigger on click. You can do something like this:
This code needs to go into your worksheet code. i.e. right click on sheet icon and click "view code".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim rInt As Range
    Dim rCell As Range

    Set rInt = Intersect(Target, Range("A1:P312"))
    If Not rInt Is Nothing Then

        Call Macro1(rInt.Row, rInt.Column)

    End If
    Set rInt = Nothing
    Set rCell = Nothing
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

EDIT: This should now work for any double click on any cell within the Range("A1:P312").